# Featured image to grayscale with PHP imagefilter - which hook to use?

Tags: uploads, hooks, post-thumbnails

Website I am working on uses b/w images everywhere and my client is a little lazy, so I need to convert any image attachment to grayscale automatically.

For that, I use something similiar to this:

```
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','themename_bw_filter');
function themename_bw_filter($meta) {
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = trailingslashit($file['path']).$meta['sizes']['themename-bw-image']['file'];
    list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);
    $image = wp_load_image($file);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    switch ($orig_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg( $image, $file );
            break;
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

Source: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-grayscale-images-in-wordpress/

If I upload the attachment through "Media > Add new", everything works as expected. However the hook `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` is apparently not fired when `featured image` for a post is set.

Can you recommend me some other hook to fire my `imagefilter`ing action to?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` only fire when the image are first uploaded. But it's also a function, so maybe you can fire it's function on a filter when the featured image is set, like `updated_post_meta`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata

Comment: I used the filter `add_attachment` for my php image filter functions. See source for filter on [trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3302)